# Дана последовательность целых чисел (Numpy). Найти количество различных чисел в этой последовательности

Tags: python, numpy

> Задача:Дана последовательность целых чисел (Numpy). Найти количество различных чисел в этой последовательности

Не подскажете, правильно ли написан код для задачи? Если нет, то подскажите, как лучше сделать.

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.random.randint(0, 15, 20)
lst1 = set(lst)
lst2 = len(lst1)
print(lst)
print(lst1)
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался `np.unique()`:

```
print(len(np.unique(lst)))
#14
```

Оптимизированные по скорости векторизированные Numpy функции работают очень быстро. Особенно это заметно на больших массивах/матрицах:

```
In [6]: a = np.random.randint(100, size=10**6)

In [7]: %timeit len(set(a))
323 ms ± 64.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [8]: %timeit len(np.unique(a))
78.3 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```